# Toolstrip order in Toolstrip container

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripcontainer

I have a toolstrip container with two toolstrips. I want to force one of them to be displayed on top of the other.
I tried setting Dock to Top for one and to Bottom for the other, but they are still displayed randomly.
I also tried using TopToolStripPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(...) but it didn't have an effect.
Even the same executable on two different pc's gives different order.
Is there a way to force the order?
Thanks

Comment: Any screen shot? Normally **We do need only 1 toolstrip**. Looks like you add your toolstrip dynamically using code? Because when you drag-n-drop 2 those toolstrips on your form, they would keep the order, I've worked with `Docking` fairly much, at least docking with other controls is OK, I don't think there is something special with `ToolStrip`, if it has, it **must be a bug** and solving an internal bug may end up for some ugly work-around.

Comment: I dragged the two into the top panel in the toolstrip container. The order gets messed up at some point. Even after setting the Dock properties.

Comment: Why don't you use normal `Panel` or simply don't use any container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these lines of code after `InitializeComponent();` to your form's constructor to ensure your specific order. This fixes any messed up settings in the designer generated code:

```cs
toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.SuspendLayout();
toolStrip1.Dock = DockStyle.None;
toolStrip2.Dock = DockStyle.None;
toolStrip1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
toolStrip2.Location = new Point(0, toolStrip1.Height);
toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.ResumeLayout();
```